# Forms with vba code and importing

Tags: excel, forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How to create an access form which has two fields for importing two different excel files, and after selecting excel files press the button to run a query (already exist) and automatically export the query result in excel sheet. I was able to create the vba code (once played the import dialog will pop up waiting the user to enter the file path then pops up another time for the second file, another dialoge for exporting the result to excel. but the problem is how to do it using Forms in Microsoft Access.please give me suggestions or reference.

Comment: It would be beneficial to see examples of what you're working with, as well as what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Boeckm, your question is a little lacking in detail :-)

If you are asking for the VBA code to fire the macro's you already have then simply create a button and add the following to the [on click] property

```
Private Sub Excel_button_Click(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False    ' Switch off "Are you sure" message

    Dim stDocName As String
    stDocName = "qry_Import file 1"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

    stDocName = "qry_Import file 2"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

    stDocName = "qry_Export file 3"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit   

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True    ' Switch on "Are you sure" message

End Sub
```

You can also build this in a single button using the wizzard (select misc, run query and select the first import query. Go back to the button and edit the [embedded macro] adding the others.  You can also add the set warning = off to the series if required).

Comment: Thank you Boeckm and Paul Cooper, I really appreciate it. I created the form with two buttons each will run different macro.

Comment: Thanks Reema, flagging the thread as answered save other folk looking to help you.  Glad it worked.  Paul